# Spring boot Integration Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm currently using spring boot for my application development. In this case it auto configures most of the beans including the data source. However I had a need to customize the Datasource configuration and hence created a new DatabaseConfig as follows.

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.password(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(...);
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();

    }
}
```

This works fine.

Now I have a spring mvc Integration test which tests the rest endpoints. I have a need to ignore the above Database config while running the tests so that spring boot auto configures an embedded datasource(HSQL db is on the class path)

How can I accomplish the same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a second dataBase and set profile for each database. While running your tests you need only to write `@ActiveProfile("nameOfProfile")` above your Test class. For example:

```
@Bean
@Profile("One")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.password(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(...);
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
@Bean
@Profile("Two")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.password(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(...);
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();

@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfile("Two")
public class Test{
}
```

Comment: This is closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create database configuration for tests and annotate test bean as primary:

```
@Configuration
public class TestDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.password(...);
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(...);
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();

    }
}
```